# How can we programmatically access options for a CanvasJS Data set?

Tags: jquery, html, canvasjs

I have the following CanvasJS Chart, serveRate and serveRate2 are defined earlier:

```
    $(".ChartContainer").CanvasJSChart({
        data: [ 
            {        
                type: "column",
                name: "Your Desired Rating",
                legendText: "Your Desired Rating",
                showInLegend: true,
                dataPoints: servRate
            },
            {
                type: "column",
                name: "Your Desired Rating",
                legendText: "Your Desired Rating",
                showInLegend: false,
                dataPoints: servRate2,
                visible: false
            },

        ] 
    });
```

I am trying to programmatically access the visible option in the second data set. I am trying

```
$(".ChartContainer").CanvasJSChart().data[1].visible
```

But I don't think I am doing it correctly? is there a way to access these options for getting or setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update options/data via chart's options object [as described here](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/).

Please try `$(".ChartContainer").CanvasJSChart().options.data[1].visible`

You can also keep a reference of the options object before passing it to the constructor and update the same later.